# Add a button on each posts of a blog

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a blog site and i want to add a "Facebook Share" button on the bottom of every post.

For the moment the solution i found is to modify the master page to call a JQuery script that will modify every post and add this button. I'm sure their is better way to do it.

I'm new in SharePoint online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your site collection > site settings page and activate the following Site Features (in this order)

1. Search Server Web Parts and Templates
2. SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Go to a blog post and edit the page.

Add the Content Editor Web Part and edit it's source toi iFrame your content.

[image]

Paste your iFramed Facebook Source code

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Change Chrome Type to None (by editing the web part) and the Title "Content Editor" won't show.

Stop editing, and you're done!

[image]

## Update

Editing a Blog Post by adding a Web Part actually updates the Blog Post Template to include the web part on all posts. See the below images on two different posts, where I've only updated one post (template).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't edit the page, when i click on the page tab on the top the "Edit Page" icon is disabled. I don't know why ! I'm on the root site (which is a blog) but i didn't configure it (it's the customer site)

Comment: And the problem with your solution is that it add only one button to my page but i want one by post.

Comment: IF you add it to the page, it will show up on all blog posts. At least in my O365 environment. Have you tried creating a new post to see if it's there!

Comment: Sorry i didn't try your solution yet because i have another weird problem. I can't edit the page ! i am searching for hours now ! When i create a new root blog i can't edit the page!